# Не устанавливаются модули в Python 3.9 через pip на новом ПК AMD Ryzen 3 PRO 3200G

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, install

Пробовал установить matplotlib и numpy и через командную строку сmd и через PyCharm Мучаюсь с 7 октября. Перечитал всё на обоих языках - русском и английском. В чём может быть загвоздка. Делаю всё правильно!) Cистема на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки:

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-7nuhteiy'
         cwd: C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\matplotlib\
    Complete output (98 lines):
    
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.3.2]
          python: yes [3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC
                      v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]]
        platform: yes [win32]
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
    
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'C:\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\73B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqitnznq3'
             cwd: C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2nmosds8\numpy
        Complete output (49 lines):
        Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
        SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
        Running from numpy source directory.
        setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
          run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
        Cythonizing sources
        Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
        SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
        Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
        Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2nmosds8\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 59, in process_pyx
            from Cython.Compiler.Version import version as cython_version
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
    
        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2nmosds8\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 235, in <module>
            main()
          File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2nmosds8\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 231, in main
            find_process_files(root_dir)
          File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2nmosds8\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 222, in find_process_files
            process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
          File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2nmosds8\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 188, in process
            processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
          File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2nmosds8\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 64, in process_pyx
            raise OSError('Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module')
        OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
            main()
          File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
          File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
            return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
          File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
            self.run_setup()
          File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
            super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
          File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
            exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
          File "setup.py", line 499, in <module>
            setup_package()
          File "setup.py", line 479, in setup_package
            generate_cython()
          File "setup.py", line 274, in generate_cython
            raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed!")
        RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\73B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqitnznq3' Check the logs for full command output.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\73B5~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpiu6dw24m', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.15']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\matplotlib\setup.py", line 242, in <module>
        setup(  # Finally, pass this all along to distutils to do the heavy lifting.
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 164, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 159, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 699, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 779, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1064, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1076, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 758, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['C:\\Python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\73B5~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpiu6dw24m', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.15']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: добавьте информации. другие модули установились нормально или все с ошибкой ?  код без модулей работает нормально ? нет ошибок с кодировкой при чтении файлов ?

Comment: Укажите команды, которые вводили в консоли. Это поможет воспроизвести ошибку.

Comment: Быстренько просмотрел traceback и вот:
1. `Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte`
2. `RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!`
3. `OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module` <-- обратите внимание на пункт 3

Comment: Ещё создай нового пользователя с английским именем или подожи когда нампи выпустит сборку для 3.9

Comment: Вопрос решен через установку Анаконды с Питоном 3.8 и использование её версии языка. До сих пор не понятно почему оригинальный Питон так  и не заработал.

Comment: Тоже была эта проблема Проблемы были из-за слишком ранней вервии питона Cегодня (11.11.2020) же есть Matplotlib под 3.9 питон и он ставится без проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Например, модули numpy и numba в python 3.9 на windows 10 x64 не устанавливаются. Ошибки читать бесполезно. Под линуксом numpy встала, numba также не устанавливается. Под 3.8 ставится всё со свистом. Напрашивается вывод - причина в 3.9. Или в том, что модули с  установщиком 3.9 ещё не подружились. pygame и opencv-python тоже не лезут под 3.9

Answer (score 0):

попробуй через командную строку
скачай архив, распакуй и закинь папку туда где Pithon, я сократил название чтобы не ругался.
строка выглядит так, (pip так же по этой команде обновился норм)

pip install C:\Python3.10\matplotlib